# Extbase looking for wrong table

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm using TYPO3 7.4.0 and I'm learning to build extensions in extbase & fluid.
I have a vendor prefix in my table names. I create three tables for my extensions. When I go in the backend and add entities in the list view on the resource folder I created, it works without any problems. When I go to the Frontend to view the index action of my entity it looks for a table without the vendor prefix in it's name. Does anyone know what that means? I create the tables in the "ext_tables.sql". I have no table mapping defined. I don't know where to change which tables extbase is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Extbase looks for table using schema `tx_extkey_domain_model_modelname`, so for `Animal` model in `zoo` ext it will be `tx_zoo_domain_model_animal`. (extkey without underscore if any!)

If you used other schema (like vendor name within table name) you need to use mapping. I.e. create file `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` in main folder of your ext and use this:

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            Vendor\Zoo\Domain\Model\Animal {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_your_own_name
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

BTW: it's best idea to keep the original naming schema. Other thing is that creating extensions manually can be tricky - at least for beginners, install [**Extension Builder**](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) ext to fast kickstart new extensions just with click-click way.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will try to add the mapping now and see if it works then. I coldn't get the extension_builder to work on 7.4.0

Comment: It's still looking for the table name without the vendor prefix even though my typoscript is included on the page.

Comment: okay I got it to work by renaming my .php Scripts inside /Configuration/TCA/. I removed the vendor prefix there and inside CREATE TABLE statements in my ext_tables.sql.

Comment: Sad news about extension_builder... workaround is keeping empty TYPO3 6.2 - where it works fine. So ufter kickstarting the ext you can just copy/paste the folder to 7.x

Comment: that's actually a really great advice thank you! gonna keep that in mind for the next ext I have to develop.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work when you want to use the repository in a symfony command .. because no typoscript is loaded there.